# Matches where an occurrence of X is Y but the corresponding Z is missing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to create a formula (or script) that is able to find all the occurrences of a plate number and return 1 if 'BOUGHT' has been found, but 'SOLD' is missing for that plate number.

The dataset that looks like this:

[image]

Column A is a list of plate numbers and B is the type ('BOUGHT' or 'SOLD').
I need to find the plate numbers for which there is a 'BOUGHT' but no 'SOLD'.

---

I tried using the formula below (and many others):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(
((VLOOKUP(A2:A,A:B,2,0)="VÉTEL")
+
(VLOOKUP(A2:A,A:B,2,0)="ELADÁS"))<>2
,1,0)))
```

---

Since nothing seems to be working, any help would be highly appreciated.

I created a sample worksheet, which can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NGup3Hw4wwUKnLG9PC1lDbSJhoeI1QByf_TbuEXaqb0/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: What if there is no `BOUGHT` found for a plate number?

Comment: @Harun24HR That does not matter, I just need to find the ones that have been BOUGHT, but not yet SOLD.

Comment: Please try my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,B2:B,"BOUGHT")>0,IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,B2:B,"BOUGHT")*(COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,B2:B,"SOLD"))=0,1,""),""))
```

See your sheet.